# how to implement SPI on STM32F3 board using standard peripheral library?

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f4discovery, slave

I am trying to implement SPI on STM32F3 Discovery board using standard peripheral library. I don't want to use HAL drivers(It is a constraint). I am not able to figure what I am missing. I am implementing the SPI in slave mode. Below is the SPI configuration and code in main function.

```
void main() {
/* Initializes the SPI communication */
SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPIx);
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Slave;
SPI_Init(SPIx, &SPI_InitStructure);

/* Initialize the FIFO threshold */
SPI_RxFIFOThresholdConfig(SPIx, SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_QF);

While(1){
// Start SPI transfer
        /* DMA channel Rx of SPI Configuration */
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = NumberOfByte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)SPIx_DR_ADDRESS;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)RxBuffer;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
DMA_Init(SPIx_RX_DMA_CHANNEL, &DMA_InitStructure);

/* DMA channel Tx of SPI Configuration */
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = NumberOfByte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)SPIx_DR_ADDRESS;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)TxBuffer;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_Low;
DMA_Init(SPIx_TX_DMA_CHANNEL, &DMA_InitStructure);

/* Enable the SPI Rx and Tx DMA requests */
SPI_I2S_DMACmd(SPIx, SPI_I2S_DMAReq_Rx, ENABLE);
SPI_I2S_DMACmd(SPIx, SPI_I2S_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);

/* Enable the SPI peripheral */
SPI_Cmd(SPIx, ENABLE);

/* Enable the DMA channels */
DMA_Cmd(SPIx_RX_DMA_CHANNEL, ENABLE);
DMA_Cmd(SPIx_TX_DMA_CHANNEL, ENABLE);

/* Wait the SPI DMA transfers complete or time out */
while (DMA_GetFlagStatus(SPIx_RX_DMA_FLAG_TC) == RESET)
{}

TimeOut = USER_TIMEOUT;
while ((DMA_GetFlagStatus(SPIx_TX_DMA_FLAG_TC) == RESET)&&(TimeOut != 0x00))
{}
if(TimeOut == 0)
 {
   //TimeOut_UserCallback();
         count += 1;
 } 

/* The BSY flag can be monitored to ensure that the SPI communication is complete.
   This is required to avoid corrupting the last transmission before disabling 
   the SPI or entering the Stop mode. The software must first wait until TXE=1
   and then until BSY=0.*/
TimeOut = USER_TIMEOUT;
while ((SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPIx, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) == RESET)&&(TimeOut != 0x00))
{}
if(TimeOut == 0)
 {
   //TimeOut_UserCallback();
         count += 1;
 }

TimeOut = USER_TIMEOUT;
while ((SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPIx, SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY) == SET)&&(TimeOut != 0x00))
{}
if(TimeOut == 0)
{
  //TimeOut_UserCallback();
        count += 1;
}


/* Clear DMA1 global flags */
DMA_ClearFlag(SPIx_TX_DMA_FLAG_GL);
DMA_ClearFlag(SPIx_RX_DMA_FLAG_GL);

/* Disable the DMA channels */
DMA_Cmd(SPIx_RX_DMA_CHANNEL, DISABLE);
DMA_Cmd(SPIx_TX_DMA_CHANNEL, DISABLE);

/* Disable the SPI peripheral */
SPI_Cmd(SPIx, DISABLE);

/* Disable the SPI Rx and Tx DMA requests */
SPI_I2S_DMACmd(SPIx, SPI_I2S_DMAReq_Rx, DISABLE);
SPI_I2S_DMACmd(SPIx, SPI_I2S_DMAReq_Tx, DISABLE);


}}
```

SPI configuration is as follows :

```
static void SPI_Config(void)
{
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

/* Enable the SPI peripheral */
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(SPIx_CLK, ENABLE);

/* Enable the DMA peripheral */
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(SPI_DMAx_CLK | TIM_DMAx_CLK, ENABLE);

/* Enable the TIM peripheral */
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(TIMx_CLK, ENABLE);

 /* Enable SCK, MOSI, MISO and NSS GPIO clocks */
 RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(SPIx_SCK_GPIO_CLK | SPIx_MISO_GPIO_CLK | 
SPIx_MOSI_GPIO_CLK |
                    SPIx_NSS_GPIO_CLK , ENABLE);

/* Enable TIM DMA trigger clock */ 
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(TIMx_TRIGGER_GPIO_CLK, ENABLE);

/* SPI pin mappings */
 GPIO_PinAFConfig(SPIx_SCK_GPIO_PORT, SPIx_SCK_SOURCE, SPIx_SCK_AF);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(SPIx_MOSI_GPIO_PORT, SPIx_MOSI_SOURCE, SPIx_MOSI_AF);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(SPIx_MISO_GPIO_PORT, SPIx_MISO_SOURCE, SPIx_MISO_AF);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(SPIx_NSS_GPIO_PORT, SPIx_NSS_SOURCE, SPIx_NSS_AF);

/* TIM capture compare pin mapping */
GPIO_PinAFConfig(TIMx_TRIGGER_GPIO_PORT, TIMx_TRIGGER_SOURCE, 
TIMx_TRIGGER_AF);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;

/* SPI SCK pin configuration */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = SPIx_SCK_PIN;
GPIO_Init(SPIx_SCK_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* SPI  MOSI pin configuration */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  SPIx_MOSI_PIN;
GPIO_Init(SPIx_MOSI_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* SPI MISO pin configuration */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = SPIx_MISO_PIN;
GPIO_Init(SPIx_MISO_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* SPI NSS pin configuration */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = SPIx_NSS_PIN;
GPIO_Init(SPIx_NSS_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* Configure the TIM channelx capture compare as DMA Trigger */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  TIMx_TRIGGER_PIN;
GPIO_Init(TIMx_TRIGGER_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* SPI configuration -------------------------------------------------------
*/
SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPIx);
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Hard;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_64;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;

/* DMA Configuration -------------------------------------------------------
*/
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize =  DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is? I have Master code in HAL drivers on other board that is working fine(Tested). So there is no issue in master side. Slave side is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

your code is in **While(1)** where you are configuring and initializing the SPI peripheral. make it in a separate function and initialize and configure only once. Also first try it without DMA and later put DMA back in.